# How to tokenize a string in Python 3.5.2

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I want to tokenize a string, and used the codes below:

```
print(raw)
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
tokens
```

'raw' is the text extracted from HTML files. I got 'raw' printed, but the last two lines did not work. I have nltk 3.2.1 and Python 3.5.2. I recall the creators of nltk said nltk was still under upgrading for Python 3.

So is there any other way to tokenize a string in the Python 3.5.2 environment? Does BeautifulSoup or other packages do that?

Comment: When you say the last two lines "did not work", could you be more specific? In particular, what exactly was the input, what was the output you expected, and what did you actually get?

Comment: If my input is the string 'Chapter I, on an exceptionally hot evening...', then the output of the last line should be something like this ['Chapter', 'I', 'on', 'an', 'exceptionally', ...]. But now nothing is showing, just looks as the code was skipped.

Comment: @Jon Ericson  And i did not get any error message.

Comment: what happens if you `print(tokens)` O.o

Comment: @Julius  what a nice solution! It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the last line code: token
I was following an example on book. After following Julius' suggestion and change it simply to

```
print(tokens)
```

It worked. So ntlk 3.2 actually works for python 3.5. that is great.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with the nltk. Your problem was that writing a variable name at the interactive prompt will print it out, but that's not the case when executing a script.

Comment: @alexis  thanks for the clarification. I was running it as script.

Comment: Yes, that was clear. The example you copied was for an interactive session.